# Could not load file or assembly Newtonsoft.Json or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: json

I am using Newtonsoft.Json assembly for Deserializing Json response. Solution builds fine, deploys fine. But when the json response is to be deserialized, I get "Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You have to check if the NewtonSoft DLL is in the global assembly cache. You have to add it manually using "gacutil /i" in Visual Studio Console or deliver it with the solution package.

Comment: if you got the error like "This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded", find the solution in here: http://www.herlitz.nu/2011/11/19/failure-adding-assembly-to-the-cache-this-assembly-is-built-by-a-runtime-newer-than-the-currently-loaded-runtime-and-cannot-be-loaded/